# Hiding a component with React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components

I have a couple of react classes in my code.
When the app fires up, the user is presented with this:

```
<div>
    <h1 className="headings" id="heading"> Football </h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
      <input type="email" placeholder="use noths email" />
      <input type="submit" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}/>
      { this.state.results ? <Decision /> : null }
        <Thanks />
 </div>
```

The state for result works because when i click the button above it turns the state from false to true.
this then returns underneath the input fields. but i would rather that it replaced the input fields above. how can this be achieved?

in summary, once the user enters the user name and email and hits submits, i want the  code to render on the page INSTEAD of the input fields rather than beneath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your output as a variable within your `render()` method:

```
let output;
```

<sup>*Note: use `var` if you're not supporting ES6.*</sup>

Then use a conditional statement to populate the variable:

```
if (this.state.results) {
  output = <Decision />;
}
else {
  output = (
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
      <input type="email" placeholder="use noths email" />
      <input type="submit" onClick={() => this.handleClick()}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now simply return the `output` within the `render()` method's `return` statement:

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1 className="headings" id="heading"> Football </h1>
    {output}
    <Thanks />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: great, exactly what i needed!

Comment: I do have one more quick question though. Say after I render the second output, what if i wanted to have yet another thing to render after that? ie the state has changed and it renders a new page but what if i wanted to then do something else on that state and re render something else? adding an else if does not work coz coz of the way ifs work (i.e. once it finds something is true it jumps out)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to turn the input elements into a separate `<Form>` components and render

```
<div>
    <h1 className="headings" id="heading"> Football </h1>
    { this.state.results ? <Decision /> : <Form handleClick={ this.handleClick }/> }
    <Thanks />
</div>
```

Where form is something like

```
const Form = props => (
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
        <input type="email" placeholder="use noths email" />
        <input type="submit" onClick={this.props.handleClick}/>
    <div>
);
```